# HealthKit: Send data from Bluetooth LE heart rate monitor to healthkit when app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, applehealth

I am working with a BLE peripheral that tracks heart rate. I can sync the data to HealthKit when the app is running and it is working fine.

I would like to send the heart rate to HealthKit without user opening the app. It is mentioned in the documentation that the direct import of data is possible from Bluetooth LE heart rate monitors to HealthKit.

Link : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hksource?language=objc

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As long as your peripheral implements the Bluetooth sig heart rate monitor service then the user can add it directly to the health app.

Comment: We need the device to be auto synced to health app

Comment: As long as it implements the heart rate profile then the user can pair it in device settings for use by the health app